# batch file to add a column in a file from another file with first field matching ,second file having large column

Tags: batch-file

I have a requirement to match the first column of both files, and add the last five columns to the first file.

File-1

```
Identifier,CandidateNumber,UserName,Language,FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,EmployeeId,Email,Internal,SSOID,CandidateUDF_1,CandidateUDF_2
5101063,62193,5101063,en,test,,test,5101063,test@invalid.com,TRUE,5101063,Ms,
```

File-2

```
Identifier,CandidateSynch,UserSynch,UserSynch,UserSynch,EmployeeUserName,EmployeeUserName,UserName,Password,UserTypeCollection,UserType1,UserType2,UserType3,UserType4,UserType5,UserType6,UserType7,UserType8,UserType9,FirstName,MiddleInitial,LastName,EmployeeNumber,WorkPhone,Email,EmployeeJobTitle,UserGroupCollection,UserGroup1,UserGroup2,Organization,Location,JobRoleCode,EmployeeStatus,UserAccountStatus,ManagerIDCollection,ManagerID,ConfigurationProfileCode,CONFIRMProfile,UDF1,UDF2,UDF3,UDF4,UDF5,UDF6,DEPTID,PersonalEmail,UDF9-Time in RoleFlag,UDF10 - LOB/BU,UDF11 - Band Level,UDF12 - Last StartDate,UDF13 - Impacted ee flag / redeploy ee status
5101063,62193,,,,5101063,5101063,5101063,T3XOROVJ12J6ZJ4,TRUE,,,,,,,,,,test3,,test4,5101063,,testing@invalid.com,test,TRUE,test,test,A5829,17677,27179,CURRENT,ACTIVE,TRUE,5100220,test,FALSE,25,,,8/17/1999,8/17/1999,9/1/2014,A700384,test@invalid.com,TRUE,TLS,,8/17/1999,FALSE
```

I am new to Windows batch scripting, and not much familiar. I tried to test below code for smaller file but it is not working.

```
@Echo off&Setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

(for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=," %%A in (F:\testscript\employeenetchange\csv\test1.csv) do (
  for /f "tokens=1-51 delims=," %%N in ('find "%%A" F:\testscript\employeenetchange\csv\test2.csv') do (
    @echo %%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%F,%%G,%%H,%%I,%%J,%%K,%%L,%%N
  )
))>>F:\testscript\employeenetchange\csv\newfile3.csv
```

I have to copy column `47` to `51` inclusive from the second to the first file.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You should understand the way `for /F "tokens=...` works. The _number of tokens_ define the _number of single-letter variables_ that will be defined. `for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=," %%A` means to define `%%A %%B %%C %%D %%E` variables. Supposedly `for /f "tokens=1-51 delims=," %%N` should define 51 variables starting at `%%N`, but there are just 13 letters from `%%N` to `%%Z`... Which characters you expect to use for variables 14..51? Anyway, the maximum number of allowed tokens in `for /F` command is 31. Also, `for /F` does _not_ identify _empty tokens_ like `62193,,,,5101063`: = _two_ tokens

Answer (score 0):

This code do what you requested:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(for /F "tokens=1* delims=," %%A in (test1.csv) do (
   for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /B "%%A," test2.csv') do set "line=%%a"
   for %%a in ("!line:,=" "!") do (
      set "last5=!last4!,%%~a"
      set "last4=!last3!,%%~a"
      set "last3=!last2!,%%~a"
      set "last2=!last!,%%~a"
      set "last=%%~a"
   )
   echo %%A,%%B,!last5!
)) > newfile3.csv
```

Output:

```
Identifier,CandidateNumber,UserName,Language,FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,EmployeeId,Email,Internal,SSOID,CandidateUDF_1,CandidateUDF_2,UDF9-Time in RoleFlag,UDF10 - LOB/BU,UDF11 - Band Level,UDF12 - Last StartDate,UDF13 - Impacted ee flag / redeploy ee status
5101063,62193,5101063,en,test,,test,5101063,test@invalid.com,TRUE,5101063,Ms,,TRUE,TLS,,8/17/1999,FALSE
```

Be aware that this code is very inefficient because it looks for the matching record in File2 via `findstr` external command. If File2 (and File1) is large, this method could take too much time...

PS - Note that you did **not** posted the desired output file, so I have no means to check that my output be correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working  only issue  if column not match then also it is adding value from previous row. Also my file 2 is large so end up with too much time to complete program :( .I appreciate your time much